# Pyinstaller Flask Application Running multiple instances

Tags: flask, instance, pyinstaller

I crated a desktop application of my Flask web app using pyinstaller. Functionality is working fine. But once I start the app, multiple instances of the same app is getting started automatically to the extent of fully occupying the CPU.Below is the command I used to create the desktop app.

```
pyinstaller --add-data "templates;templates" --add-data "static;static" app.py
```

There are multiple instances of app, like my screenshot shows:

[image: screenshot]

How can i fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this by giving the --onefile option. Couldn't figure out why the default version had this issue though.